# Embedding Google Waves in Blogs and Search Engines

Tags: blogs, google-wave, blogger

After watching the cool [Google Wave Developer Preview at Google I/O 2009](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_UyVmITiYQ) I started wondering that it would be cool to integrate Google Wave with my [blog](http://devblogi.pl). I'd like to replace the built-in Blogger comments with comments based on Google Wave.

But my impression is that it's all JavaScript-based.

This makes me wonder whether Google bots (or bots from any other search engine) would be able to read any content embedded in a blog this way? If there is no such feature then embedding Google Wave inside a blog/site/portal is a total mix-up.

Does anyone knows anything more in this topic?

I'll appreciate any comments. :)

Comment: Google bot will anyway be able to spider the content as the databases are with Google. :-)

Comment: Is this a guesswork? I'd rather be sure before implementing this. :)